# Error C++: Program Received Signal SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, allegro

Al colocar una imagen en pantalla se detiene y me manda un error, pero si omito la imagen, el programa corre normal únicamente me lanza un error de "el proyecto se ha detenido" cuando trato de cargar la imagen en pantalla.

este es el código fuente:

```
#include <allegro.h>

int main() {
    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();

    set_color_depth(32);
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 640, 700, 0, 0);

    BITMAP *buffer = create_bitmap(640, 700);
    clear_to_color(buffer, 0x333320);

    BITMAP *hello;

    hello = load_bitmap("hello3.bmp",NULL);

    while (!key[KEY_ESC]){
        blit(buffer, screen, 0, 0, 0, 0, 700, 480);
     //dimensiones de la imagen = 102*79
        blit(hello, screen, 0, 0, 20, 20, 102, 79); // imagen en pantalla
    }

    readkey();
    destroy_bitmap(buffer);
    return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN()
```

Error en pantalla:

*Program Received Signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.*

Comment: Has probado algún `printf` o `cout`? Tal vez hacer debug con `gdb`?

Comment: Comprueba que los punteros recibidos de allegro son buenos (`buffer`, `hello`, ...)

Answer (score 1):

El error [`SIGSEGV`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV):

> Es la [señal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Se%C3%B1al_(inform%C3%A1tica)) enviada a un [proceso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proceso_(inform%C3%A1tica)) cuando se hace una referencia a memoria no válida, o [fallo de segmentación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallo_de_segmentaci%C3%B3n).

A grandes rasgos, has intentado leer o escribir sobre memoria no válida. Es muy posible que la falla de tu imagen haya fallado, según [el manual de Allegro](https://liballeg.org/stabledocs/en/alleg010.html) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### Cargando archivos de imágen
>
> [BITMAP](https://liballeg.org/stabledocs/en/alleg001.html#BITMAP) *load_bitmap(const char *filename, [RGB](https://liballeg.org/stabledocs/en/alleg001.html#RGB) *pal);
>
> Carga un mapa de bits desde una imagen. **La paleta se guardará en el segundo parámetro, que debe ser una formación de 256 estructuras RGB**. Ahora mismo esta función da soporte a archivos BMP, LBM, PCX y TGA, determinando el tipo a partir de la extensión del archivo.
>
> ...
>
> Valor de retorno: **Devuelve un puntero al mapa de bits o NULL en caso de error**.

Así que, o bien la función ha intentado escribir en el segundo parámetro (que tú has pasado como `NULL`) o bien ha fallado la carga de la imagen y como no lo compruebas, `hello` contiene `NULL` y al llamar a `blit(hello, screen, 0, 0, 20, 20, 102, 79);` falla.

#### Sugerencia.

Usa `load_bitmap` de la manera que sugiere el manual:

```
RGB paleta[256]{};
if (BITMAP *hello = load_bitmap("hello3.bmp", paleta)) {
    while (!key[KEY_ESC]){
        blit(buffer, screen, 0, 0, 0, 0, 700, 480);
     //dimensiones de la imagen = 102*79
        blit(hello, screen, 0, 0, 20, 20, 102, 79); // imagen en pantalla
    }
}
```